# why __del__ dunder method act different in vs code vs jupyter notebook

Tags: python, oop

**del** methods in python class has two different output in different text editors

```
class test:
    def __init__(self) :
        print("init")
    def __del__(self):
        print("del")
a=test()
```

**outpuu in vs code :**

*init
del*
**out put in jupyter :**

*init*

Comment: Doesn't `jupyter` maintain state?

Comment: How are you using vscode to run this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the Python script in the terminal (which is similar as in vscode), after the last line has been executed, the script terminates. When a script terminates, the *desctructor* of the class `test()` is called. A desctructor is defined in `__del__()` method in a class.

In Jupyter notebook, the script does not terminate and is up for your next code chunk (apols the terminology might be slightly off here). The `__del__()` method is not called.

Answer (score 1):

It is explicitely stated in Python Language Reference. Data model / Special method names / Basic customization says (emphasize mine):

> object.**del**(self)
>
> Called when the instance is about to be destroyed...
> **It is not guaranteed that **del**() methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits**.

That means that different environments may have different usage regarding the calling of `__del__`